# Comparing Three Dates to Get Latest in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

In my Mongo collection I need to compare three dates, and find the most recent one. I'm wondering if there's a short-hand or native MongoDB way of doing this?

When comparing two dates in vanilla JS I could so something like:

```
let compareDates = (date1, date2) => {
   if (date1>date2) return ("Date1 > Date2");
   else if (date1<date2) return ("Date2 > Date1");
   else return ("Date1 = Date2"); 
  }

console.log(compare_dates(new Date('11/14/2018 00:00'), new Date('11/14/2018 00:00')));
console.log(compare_dates(new Date('11/14/2018 00:01'), new Date('11/14/2018 00:00')));
console.log(compare_dates(new Date('11/14/2018 00:00'), new Date('11/14/2018 00:01')));
```

... but this would get long with three dates. Is there a shorter way to compare three dates and return the most recent date?

Let's assume a simplified model like this:

```
{
    _id: '123',
    date1: {
      type: Date,
    },
    date2: {
      type: Date,
    },
    date3: {
      type: Date,
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model looks like this:

```
{
    date1: ISODate("1990-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    date2: ISODate("1980-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    date3: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
}
```

You can simply use [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) to get recent date:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            recentDate: { $max: [ "$date1", "$date2", "$date3" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Excellent! `$max` sounds like the perfect solution here. Thanks, @mickl!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some POJS solutions, Math.max works but returns a time value. Alternatively, sort them in an array and get the last one:

```js
var dates = [
  new Date('2018-01-01'),
  new Date('2018-01-03'),
  new Date('2018-01-02') 
];

// Returns a new Date
console.log(new Date(Math.max(...dates)));

// Returns one of the dates, sorts and shortens the array
console.log(dates.sort((a,b)=>a-b).pop()); 

// Returns a reference to one of the dates, sorts but doesn't shorten the array
console.log(dates.sort((a,b)=>a-b).slice(-1)[0]);
```